# dimension of subspace $V = \{A \in M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{C}) : \textrm{tr}(A) = 0, A^\textrm{T} = -\bar{A}\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let V be the subspace defined by

$V = \{A\in M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{C}) : \textrm{tr}(A) = 0, A^\textrm{T} = -\bar{A}\}$ and note $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ with inner product $<A,B> = -\textrm{tr}(AB)$. Find an orthonormal basis for $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to this inner product.

I was able to find one element of this basis
$$ \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     0 & -\frac{1}{2} \\
     \frac{1}{2} & 0
  \end{array} \right]
$$

but I'm not sure what the other could be, seeing as we are finding a basis over $\mathbb{R}$. Further, I'm not sure what the dimension of the subspace ought to be, so I don't know how many elements to find. How would I figure this out?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: $-\mathrm{tr}(AB)$ is not an inner product on $M_2(\Bbb C)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can write $V$ as 
\begin{equation}
V = \{\begin{pmatrix}ia & -b+ic\\  b + ic & -ia\end{pmatrix}| a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}\}
\end{equation}
So we can see that the basis are
\begin{equation}
\{t_1, t_2, t_3\} = \{\frac{1}{{\sqrt{2}}}\begin{pmatrix}i & 0\\  0 & -i\end{pmatrix},\frac{1}{{\sqrt{2}}}\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1\\  1 & 0\end{pmatrix},\frac{1}{{\sqrt{2}}}\begin{pmatrix}0 & i\\  i & 0\end{pmatrix}\}
\end{equation}
It is then easy to see that the dimension is 3. Note that the vector space $V$ you described is also known as the lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$. The basis can easily be verified to be orthonormal $tr({t_i^\dagger t_j}) = \delta_{ij}$.